# nvidia driver install for ubuntu 14.04 using xorg-edgers ppa

Tags: purge, blacklist

```
Graphics card: Nvidia GT740
OS: ubuntu 14.04 64bit
```

I tried to install nvidia driver in the following way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended gives:

driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party free recommended
```

Then I intend to do:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

My question is do I have to do:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau before i install nvidia-340
```

Do I have to blacklist anything?

Answer (score 1):

By default you shouldnt need to remove nouveau grafics but if you have any type of conflict remove it, i generally just download then and install them and it works fine.